# Stack update feature is not working with volumes when we add a extra node (scaling scenario)

Tags: openstack

I have a stack template with 3 nodes , each node having a volume attached ! Now i updated my template with additional node and additional volume for that node ! This results in user_data update of a node in template ! And when i perform stack update feature , it gives me error: Invalid volume: Volume 01e40c6e-4467-42fe-ba9d-ce7012db8978 status must be available or downloading to reserve, but the current status is in-use.

This shows for the node (where user_data is changed) and yes it is currently in use ! Then how one can update the stack using stack update feature of openstack with volumes ?

Below is the file i create on that node user_data , so adding a node updates this user_data as well:

```
cat << 'EOF' > mydata.json
            {
              "hosts":{
                "nodes":{
                  "node-1":{
                    "my_lan":{
                      "hostname":"node-1",
                      "ip":"~node-1-my_lan-ip~",
                      "interface": "eth0"
                    }
                  },
                  "node-2":{
                    "my_lan":{
                      "hostname":"node-2",
                      "ip":"~node-2-my_lan-ip~",
                      "interface": "eth0"
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of the stack template?

Comment: i just updated the post , see if it helps you !  So when i add a new node , this user_data also gets updated on that node (for which it is originally creating volume error)

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar used case where we create two separate stacks, One for vm and other one for cinder volumes.

Create cinder volume stack first and then associate the cinder volume id with the vm stack.

This used case will give you fine control on maintaining the cinder volumes and vm.

Obviously any change in VM user data is going to recreate the vm instead of rebuild action and that is what you are running onto.